# Angular and cloudinary integration error?

Tags: angularjs, cloudinary

I am using clodinary - angular app in github mentioned below
https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular

But in that app, it shows only uploading image with image preset.But I need to upload image with API key.I changed my code as

In my app.js

```
app.config(['cloudinaryProvider' , function (cloudinaryProvider) {
            cloudinaryProvider
            .set("cloud_name", "********")
            .set("api_key", "**********")
            .set("api_secret", "****************");
            //.set("upload_preset", "*******");

        }
    ]);

I commented upload preset and changed 'unsigned' to 'signed' in cloudinary dashboard.
```

In my service

```
promise = $upload.upload({
                                    url: "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/" + cloudinary.config().cloud_name + "/upload",
                                    data: {
                                        api_key: cloudinary.config().api_key,
                                        api_secret: cloudinary.config().api_secret,
                                        tags: 'myphotoalbum',
                                        context: 'photo=' + title,
                                        file: file
                                    }
                                }).progress(function (e) {})
                                .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                    return data;
                                }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                                    return data;
                                });
```

But it shows "Bad Request Error".How can I fix this issue.Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: Anybody knows the answer?

Comment: if you are uploading an image `signed`, it must have a `signature`, which **cannot** be created by the browser.  therefore, `signed` uploads can **only** be performed from a server side component. The file would be sent to your server, then from your server to cloudinary.  Therefore, you wouldn't even use the angular component for cloudinary at all, you would use the plugin for your specific server.  as an example, here is the node documentation on this process:  http://cloudinary.com/documentation/node_image_upload#direct_uploading_from_the_browser

Comment: further reading suggests you *could possibly* generate a signature in your app:  http://cloudinary.com/documentation/upload_images#creating_api_authentication_signatures

Comment: If I change signed to unsigned  then how  should I rewrite my code?

Comment: Please refer to the Cloudinary Angular [Sample project](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular/tree/master/samples/photo_album), and to [this controller](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular/blob/master/samples/photo_album/app/js/controllers.js) in specific.